# objective-c: Webservice, How to get two elements after parsing through NSXMLParser?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsxmlparser

I am using the below code which gives me the string  of one element after parsing, while I want to get another element's text on the base of first element's result.

e.g. I am getting bool value from **ResponseType** and now on the base of that value I want to get another element's ("TotalAmt") value. and if ResponseType is 0 anohter field appears in code which is DeclineReason  and then I want to get DeclineReason's value.

```
<AuthorizeResult>
            <ResultCode>Success</ResultCode>
            <RequestTime>2011-09-30T01:42:54.1834586-04:00</RequestTime>
            <ResultObj>
               <RequestId>55258</RequestId>
               <ResponseType>1</ResponseType>
               <UserType>Permanent</UserType>
               <RequestDate>2011-09-30T05:42:54.481</RequestDate>
               <TransactionId>0081315926057572</TransactionId>
               <TransactionCode>001440</TransactionCode>
               <TotalAmt>1</TotalAmt>
               <UserId>47</UserId>
            </ResultObj>
         </AuthorizeResult>
```

I code this but its not workin g and get only the value of "ResponseType"

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ResponseType"]) 
    { 
        if (!soapResults) 
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
            elementFound = YES;
        }
    }
}


//---when the text in an element is found---
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (elementFound) 
    { 
        [soapResults appendString: string];
    }   
}


//---when the end of element is found---
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ResponseType"]) 
    { //---displays the country--- 
        NSLog(@"%@", soapResults); 
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Response Type!" message:soapResults delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show]; 
        [alert release]; 
        [soapResults setString:@""]; 
        elementFound = FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call [xmlParser parse] two times.

```
qelementName = @"ResponseType";
[soapResults setString:@""]; 
[xmlParser parse];              
ResponseType =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", soapResults];

qelementName = @"TotalAmt";
[soapResults setString:@""]; 
[xmlParser parse];
TotalAmt = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", soapResults];
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

How about

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ResultObj"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"Reason"])

in both didStartElement and didEndElement?